# Can anything be done about downvotes and closures out of hate?

Tags: discussion

My question

[when is the Trimurti referred to first?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27017/when-is-the-trimurti-referred-to-first)

received 2 downvotes.  Nothing but hatred directed at the poster can explain this.  These acts are immature and would impede the "graduation" of the site.

Comment: Nothing can be done about downvotes. Posting about downvotes on meta is useless. It is already asked on meta before. About closevotes, it is also discussed on meta. See my question about close voting.  If it is due to hate, mods will take care. I have observed it on other questions also. Some are voting to close good questions  as off-topic and primarily opinion based.

Comment: Whar we are seeing now is meta-hate - hatred directed at attempts to stop the hate.  There are strange posters here.

Comment: Why did this meta post receive upvote? How is this useful? Now, we will discuss about downvotes on questions on posts on meta? There is quality for meta site also. People from other sites are watching. Please don't post about downvotes on meta.

Comment: Let us hope this person doesn't know what "facepalm" means.  If he/she does - this is street language.

Comment: That particular post (on main) does not deserve downvotes. The answer given there is also wrong but it got upvotes. And such things do affect the site quality. Talking about ur posts and downvotes then are there any such posts at all from u that did not receive downvotes? I would like to think that some of those were cast simply because the posts belonged to u. It should not be that way but it happens. And I think it's happening with u in particular. @SK

Comment: @Rickross, I haven't downvoted many of SK's main posts and not even this meta post. However, complaining about every issue in meta, looks immature to me. It's devaluating the meta by posting so many questions so often. This actually hides lots of question which are important. I have several posts which are downvoted even though with scriptures. The best example is [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19310/1049). Whether people should downvote or not, is their discretion. However, meta is shared by all. Let it be used wisely.

Comment: @iammilind I had already requested SK to be substantial with his Meta posts.

Comment: The posts hurting beliefs would obviously get downvotes.

Comment: you told me to grin and bear it when scripture was cited to imply that if you read Siva purana you would go to hell @pandya

Answer (score -2):

Most posters seem to be computer-geeks also and so this problem can be tackled as a computer-science problem.

(1) Discover keywords that can evoke "legitimate" hate - Siva-Vishnu being the ultimate one.

(2) discover topics that can evoke legitimate hate - like caste system, sati and so forth

(3) After filtering these reasons out - any consistent patterns of downvoting/votes to delete can only be due to ad hominem reasons.